# weird normal map bake from high to low poly

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I have baked my high poly to my low poly using Cycles, but at the render results i cant get the right bumps.

Here is my low poly character

[image]

and my high poly character.

[image]

I applied the normal map and the base colour to the low poly and it worked fine,

[image]

but in render preview i get the following results, weird lines and weak bumping instead of my normal map bake sculpt.

[image]

nodes used

[image]

Is there a way that i can get the right texture from my bake?